# Deriving expectation and variance for Binomial random variable

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, expected-value, binomial-theorem, variance

I've seen several relatively length derivations of $E[X], \text{var}(X)$, where $X \sim binomial$. Actually, in fact, all the resources seem to use the lengthy approach.

The lengthier approach is doing something like:
\begin{align}
    E[X] = \sum_{x=0}^n x \binom{n}{x} p^x (1 - p)^{n - x} \\
    = \sum_{x=0}^n x \frac{n!}{(n-x)!x!} p^x (1 - p)^{n - x} \\
    = \sum_{x=1}^n x \frac{n!}{(n-x)!x!} p^x (1 - p)^{n - x} \\
    = np\sum_{x=1}^n \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-x)!(x-1)!} p^{x-1} (1 - p)^{n - x} \\
    = np\sum_{x=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-x-1)!(x)!} p^{x} (1 - p)^{n - x - 1} \\
    = np \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{x}p^x(1 - p)^{n - x - 1} \\
    = np (p + 1 - p)^{n-1} \\
    = np
\end{align}

and analogously for $E[X^2]$ to get the eventual variance.

The really simply approach, and I'm not sure if it is fully valid, is to just introduce $B_i$ as a bernoulli random variable where $B_i = 1$ with probability $p$.

Then, easily,

\begin{align}
    E[X] = E[B_1 + \ldots B_n] = nE[B_1] = np
\end{align}

Is this approach valid or is it flawed in some way? The one thing I am concerned about is in the former lengthier approach, we consider all possibly values of $X$ and their associated probabilities. Am I really doing that with this bernoulli/indicator variable approach? If not, does this make this approach invalid?

Comment: This is a completely valid approach, given that a binomial random variable is just a sum of indicator variables.

Comment: I agree with @Hyperion.  When it comes to the variance calculation your sum-of-indicators approach is far simpler than the lengthy binomial coefficient calculation.  Good job!